# Best way to keep track of an item when shuffling, of where they were before shuffeling

Tags: performance, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a list of questions. Each question have at least 2 answers to choose from. There is only one option that is right, for now.

Having the answers in the same order teaches the students of where the answer is located instead of learning the actual answer to the question. Hench shuffling the answers is good.

Problem: I use the index to keep track of the correct answer for each question. This way wont work with shuffling the answers.

Current question structure:

```
question structure {
  correct answer, index of where the correct answer is in the array below
  list of answers, simple array of strings
}
```

When shuffling (Fisher–Yates shuffle) the correct answer is moved in the array, the index change.

One possible solution is to switch the structure to this but it would be inefficient:

```
question structure {
  list of answers
}

answer structure {
  boolean correct answer (true, false)
  string answer
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
How do I keep track of the correct answer in the array?

I was pondering of keeping an array of the answers in one list then use a map and shuffle that map. Seems like overkill, complicated and memory and cpu hungry. That way i could keep the index to the correct answer.

I've stared myself blind of this problem.

Note: This program prototype is written in C# but it shouldn't matter that much.

Answer (score 1):

During the shuffle, the algorithm is choosing two indices and exchanging the array elements at those indices.  All you need to do is check if the current answer index is one of those indices.  If so, change it to the other one.

*eg*

```
// Given two elements i, and j which will be used to swap, update answer index
if answerIndex = i then
    answerIndex <- j
else if answerIndex = j then
    answerIndex <- i
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it was me, I would identify each answer with an `int ID`, and then just identify the correct answer by the ID (Something like `int Correct_ID`. So, when the user chooses a question, all you have to do is compare Correct_ID and the chosen question's ID, regardless of how many times you shuffle.

It's similiar to the boolean idea, but opens other possibilities: if you perform other actions on the answers, this ID could also come in handy, since it's quicker to compare `int`'s than `string`'s.
*(If I remember a situation to serve as an example, I'll update, can't come up with one at the moment)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a Python example.

```
>>> items = [
...     (0, 'Apple'),
...     (1, 'Banana'),
...     (2, 'Orange'),
...     (3, 'Pear'),
... ]
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(items)
>>> items
[(1, 'Banana'), (2, 'Orange'), (0, 'Apple'), (3, 'Pear')]
>>> for key, value in items:
...     print key, value
... 
1 Banana
2 Orange
0 Apple
3 Pear
>>>
```

The key point being you can shuffle records, where each record has an ID associated with it, not just the string value.

You can store unique IDs for each item, or just mark one of them as the "correct" answer (so each item would have a True or False, and only one would be True).